# jQuery :: Dynamically create menu items

Tags: jquery, css

I am learning jQuery and dont know much about it so please bear with me.

I have created a menu with Search AddNew Edit Delete menu items. Now my requirement is - whenever I will click on the AddNew or Edit link/button, my code should replace "AddNew" or "Edit" menu item with Update and Cancel menu items. These menu items should not let select another menu items unless cancel or update is pressed. once I will click "cancel" or "update" menu item, both menu items should disappear and "Edit" menu item should be back. I tried but somehow its not working  any good.

```
    <body>
    <div class="menu">
        <a id="aSearch" href="#">Search</a><br />
        <a id="aAddNew" href="#">Add New</a><br />
        <a id="aEdit" href="#">Edit</a><br />
        <a id="aDelete" href="#">Delete</a><br />
    </div>
    </body>
```

Can you please help me to solve this ? You can find jsFiddle here : [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/developer2013/ZkGbw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using only hyperlinks, it would be better approach to use list as Mooseman does.

```
        $(function () {
        $("#lnkEdit").click(function () {
          $("#lnkCancelUpdate").toggle();
          $("#lnkEdit").toggle();           
        });
        $("#lnkCancel").click(function () {
          $("#lnkCancelUpdate").toggle();
          $("#lnkEdit").toggle();
        });
    });
```

Following is updated version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkGbw/19/

Pls vote if it helped.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much khurram.. it didnt solve my complete problem but it gave me idea how to proceed.. thanks again :)